# Jemos PODAM StackOverflowError

Tags: java, jemos-podam

Please, tell me how correctly to do filling with use PodamFactory. I get `StackOverflowError` for `productList`(source class List) when call `podamFactory.manufacturePojo(Product)`.

Product (A) Source :

```
public class Product {

    private String productName;

    private String productDescription;

    private Double price;

    private Boolean availability;

    private List<Product> productList;

    // getters & setters

}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseSimpleClassTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:253)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignatureSuffix(SignatureParser.java:270)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:244)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:228)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeArgument(SignatureParser.java:319)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeArguments(SignatureParser.java:284)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseSimpleClassTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:260)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignatureSuffix(SignatureParser.java:270)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:244)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:228)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:359)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseZeroOrMoreTypeSignatures(SignatureParser.java:469)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFormalParameters(SignatureParser.java:446)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseMethodTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:436)
    sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseMethodSig(SignatureParser.java:141)
    sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.parse(ConstructorRepository.java:37)
    sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.parse(ConstructorRepository.java:25)
    sun.reflect.generics.repository.AbstractRepository.<init>(AbstractRepository.java:56)
    sun.reflect.generics.repository.GenericDeclRepository.<init>(GenericDeclRepository.java:30)
    sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.<init>(ConstructorRepository.java:33)
    sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.<init>(MethodRepository.java:28)
    sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.make(MethodRepository.java:41)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericInfo(Method.java:94)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:282)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufacturePojoInternal(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1464)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufacturePojo(PodamFactoryImpl.java:109)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufactureAttributeValue(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1681)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufactureAttributeValue(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1568)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.fillCollection(PodamFactoryImpl.java:2078)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.resolveCollectionValueWhenCollectionIsPojoAttribute(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1973)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufactureAttributeValue(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1646)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufacturePojoInternal(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1485)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufacturePojo(PodamFactoryImpl.java:109)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufactureAttributeValue(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1681)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufactureAttributeValue(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1568)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.fillCollection(PodamFactoryImpl.java:2078)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.resolveCollectionValueWhenCollectionIsPojoAttribute(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1973)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufactureAttributeValue(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1646)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufacturePojoInternal(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1485)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufacturePojo(PodamFactoryImpl.java:109)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufactureAttributeValue(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1681)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.manufactureAttributeValue(PodamFactoryImpl.java:1568)
    uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl.fillCollection(PodamFactoryImpl.java:2078)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very probably here:

```
private List<Product> productList;
```

Looks like whatever process takes places goes recursive here. You have to break that recursivity.

After some googling around however, it looks strange since the API you use [has support for recursivity](http://tedone.typepad.com/blog/2011/04/podam-journal-added-support-for-recursive-hierarchies.html) -- but the case in the link is for an instance, not a collection of instances.

Try a more recent version?

**EDIT** there is a `@PodamCollection` annotation, maybe it can help you

Comment: Yes,I also think that the problem is in `private List<Product> productList;`. I tried use versions - `3.0.2.RELEASE` and `3.0.3.RELEASE`(last)

Comment: Try and limit the number of elements created in the list (the annotation I mentioned allows for this), does it work then?

Comment: Thank you for answer but with annotation `@PodamCollection(nbrElements = 3)` I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.1.3 PODAM handles this situation gracefully by detecting loop in POJO dependencies and cutting recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Try podamFactory.manufacturePojo(ArrayList.class, Product.class)

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer